# What does "take" mean in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

The verb "take" has a lot of meanings. I can't undsrstand what it means in this context?

> 85 min Villa 2 Everton 0         Onana, not up to speed
> understandably, dawdles in midfield and is mugged by Buendia who
> brings the ball forward, Watkins **takes a defender** with him as he
> splits to the right, receives the pass and rolls it back across for
> Buendia to slot in.

Answer (score 1):

Would you understand if I said, "Watkins took an umbrella with him, when he went to the shops."?

It really is the same meaning: "To move something from one place to another".  In this case, Watkins causes the defender to move from the centre to the right.  This opened up the defense, giving space for Buendia to get into a scoring position.

Comment: Yes, that's clear now. Thanks a lot.